# Far-future fantasy novel where a character turns out to be an android

Tags: story-identification, androids

I'm looking for a book which mostly belongs to the fantasy genre but has a sci-fi background.

Over the course of the story it is revealed that it's set in our far future and that all the fantasy creatures that appear were once genetically engineered by a bored and decadent civilization.

I remember one person turning out to be an android still 'alive' and remembering it all.

Comment: What fantasy creatures were there? When did you read this book?

Comment: Richard's right, we'll need more information. I actually think I may know this book, but without more details I can't quite grab it's name from the aether. I feel like Tantalus.

Comment: I don't remember much about the fantasy creatures. I think there were dwarves, centaurs. But that's probably not very helpful. I think another ice age had come and people were traveling once to the glacial wall. The android was female and over the ages could keep herself going by finding old underground reactor sites where she could exchange her fuel cell.

Comment: It sounds a lot like the Dragonriders of Pern book series.  The dragons were genetically engineered and as the series continues the people of Pern discover a super computer that reveals this to them as well as the fact that they were originally colonist from the planet Earth: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern

Comment: Thanks, but it's not from the Pern Trilogy, but written as a single novel. Also not a long one, less than an inch thick.

Answer (score 11):

**"[World Enough, and Time](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13593859-world-enough-and-time)" by James Kahn.**

The first book in the "[New World](http://premiere.fastpencil.com/world-enough-and-time)" trilogy.

[image: World enough and time]

Comment: Wow, thanks Richard, that's the one! I've been looking for ages! Thanx a lot!

Comment: You're welcome but rojomoke gets the credit. I just added a pic and some links